# C - Storing a char array multiple times in a 2d char* array

Tags: c, arrays

The problem here is that whenever I change the contents of studName the contents inside studArr change too.

If the input looks like this `(AAA,BBB,CCC)` I first store `AAA` inside `studName` and then store `studName` into `studArr`.

I'm trying to make:

```
studArr[0][1] = "AAA"

studArr[0][2] = "BBB"

studArr[0][3] = "CCC
```

but when I use this code all of them equal `CCC`. Is there a way I can fix this?

```
for (j = 0; j < NumCourses + 1; j++){
    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(ifp)) != ')'){
        if (c == ','){
            studName[3] = '\0'; // ends sting with null char
            studArr[j][k+1] = studName;
            k++;
            i = 0;
        }
        else{
            studName[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    studName[3] = '\0'; // ends sting with null char
    studArr[j][k+1] = studName; // store studName in studArr

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: char* studArr[NumCourses][1024];
char studName[3];

where NumCourses is just a constant

Comment: If you store studName[3] = '\0'; than you should declate char studName[4];
In C array index is counted from 0 to N-1, where N is number of elements in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the assignment:

> studArr[j][k+1] = studName;

you store a pointer to char[] studName.
You should allocate memory for every instance, like here:

```
studArr[j][k+1] = strdup(studName);
```

Note: remember to free allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

`studName` is a pointer, and each `studArr[j][N]` is being set to the same pointer.  The *contents* found by the pointer are being updated, but all the duplicate copies of the same pointer will show the last contents only.

You probably need to use `strncpy()`, or the like.  Specific details really depend on the code you have not yet shown, like declarations.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it's because you assign all pointer to point to `studName`, and it will always contain the last read string.

You need to *duplicate* the string instead of just assigning the pointer. Either use `strdup` (which means you have to free the memory later) or make each entry an array and copy into it.